# Enum is not a valid type for an enumerated mapping

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm having a real head-scratcher over the following exception which is thrown when I try and deploy my webapp to a Glassfish container (both static shell and server). Basically, I have an entity class which has the following property:

```
    @Entity
    public class Anniversary implements Serializable, Comparable<Anniversary>
    {
     ...

        @Enumerated
        private AnniversaryType type;

     ....Rest of class
     }
```

Which refers to an enumerated class that is declared as follows:

```
 public enum AnniversaryType
```

The program builds without complaint in Netbeans 8.0 using a standard Maven project, but when it is deployed the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7151] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):         org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class com.mycompany.anniversaries_final.AnniversaryType] for the   attribute [type] on the entity class [class com.mycompany.anniversaries_final.Anniversary] is not a     valid type for an enumerated mapping. The attribute must be defined as a Java enum.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForEnumeratedAttribute(ValidationException.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.converters.EnumeratedMetadata.process(EnumeratedMetadata.java:115)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processEnumerated(MappingAccessor.java:1684)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.processEnumerated(BasicAccessor.java:467)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1769)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1796)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:419)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processMappingAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processMappingAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:1648)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1234)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:697)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1793)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:576)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
... 64 more
```

. I am baffled! I have looked at both of the following answers: 
[JPA and enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526760/jpa-and-enum-type) and [jaxws and EclipseLink refuses to use enums from lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101727/jaxws-and-eclipselink-refuses-to-use-enums-from-lib) both of which offer answers if the class is in a separate jar file,but in my case it is not (as far as I know). I did have another issue with this enum elsewhere in the app where I was using it as a map key and had to explicitly name the table and key values as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364922.

I'm totally stumped....any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed! The issue was being caused by the following line in the enumerated class:

```
return Arrays.asList(values()).stream().filter(type -> {
          return type.isCultural();
       }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I seem to be having issues with using streams in entity classes in general; when I use them they seem to cause all sorts of apparently unrelated exceptions. I have filed a bugreport with Glassfish and await their response...

Comment: I've also run into this problem. Your post has led me to the answer (solution to be coded...)- thanks! On [https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jpa_and_java_se_8](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jpa_and_java_se_8), it states: **Streams are not supported in the current release of JPA (JPA 2.1 - JSR 338) as it predates Java SE 8. But this is clearly a potential RFE for the next update of JPA (see this specification RFE here). In addition, some of the JPA implementations have already started to add support for Java 8 Streams (e.g. Hibernate and EclipseLink).**